# How to put a tableView inside a section Header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I’m trying to put a tableView inside a collectionView sectionHeader. I tried adding a tableView to the header in storyboard and then setting its class to tableViewController.swift but that didn’t work.
(I’m using swift)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by putting the tableview inside the header section? why not put it above the collection view ?

Comment: The collectionView has icons and then the header was intended to show images which the user can swipe through. I was going to put another collectionView inside one cell of the tableView which would display the images. Another cell I was going to but some buttons. I was going to put it in the header so that it scrolls with the collectionView. @DarkInnocence

Comment: I'll code it first and hopefully it works..

Comment: Just to clarify. There’s a collectionview with a header. Inside this header is a tableView, then inside a tableView cell is another collection view, (other tableView cells have buttons). Thanks @DarkInnocence

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? @DarkInnocence

Comment: still working on it.. will post the answer soon, I'm close enough I guess..

Comment: Any luck so far? : ) @DarkInnocence

Comment: Nvm, got it working. Thanks anyway @DarkInnocence

Comment: Nope still cant get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a bit i did manage to get it working properly.
First i created a header as normal, then created an IBOutlet of the tableView.
Then I simply setup the header file like a tableViewController is setup, connected to the dataSource and delegate in awakeFromNib and done.

```
class HomeHeader: UICollectionReusableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
       //tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1 //number of sections
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return 5 //number of cells
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
       // cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    }



}
```